# Indexdb DOM Exception 18 Security IOS 10 Iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ios10

I'm trying to use indexdb inside an Iframe that is running inside cordova app on ios but I get an **SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): IDBFactory.open() called in an invalid security context**. I found that this problem was fix on IOS 10 beta 5 so I download the IOS 10.1 beta 1 and try on real device, but I still can't make it work. Here is the link to the bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11524. I'm using also Xcode 8.1 beta.

```
SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): IDBFactory.open() called in an    invalid security context
open
_callee$ — database.js:11
tryCatch — runtime.js:61
invoke — runtime.js:329
step — database.js:3
initializePromise
Promise
(anonymous function) — database.js:3
tryCatch — runtime.js:61
invoke — runtime.js:329
step — index.js:3
promiseReactionJob
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm on iOS11 with ionic and I have this exact same problem.